# How do implement classes into my Nibbles remake?

Tags: python, class, oop, pygame

So I made a Nibbles/Snake remake by following the pygame tutorials on thenewboston youtube channel by sentdex. I made a lot of minor aesthetic changes, but overall, it's the same game. Here's the code for that:

```
import pygame
import time
import random

pygame.init()

# A few extra colors just for testing purposes.
WHITE = (pygame.Color("white"))
BLACK = (  0,   0,  0)
RED   = (245,   0,  0)
TURQ  = (pygame.Color("turquoise"))
GREEN = (  0, 155,  0)
GREY  = ( 90,  90, 90)
SCREEN = (800, 600)
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode(SCREEN)
#Set the window title and picture
pygame.display.set_caption('Slither')
ICON = pygame.image.load("apple10pix.png")

pygame.display.set_icon(ICON)
CLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 20
FONT = pygame.font.SysFont("arial", 25)
SNAKE_SIZE = 10 # The width of the snake in pixels, not the length. Start length is defined in the game loop.
APPLE_SIZE = 10
TINY_FONT = pygame.font.SysFont("candara", 15)
SMALL_FONT = pygame.font.SysFont("candara", 25)
MED_FONT = pygame.font.SysFont("candara", 50)
LARGE_FONT = pygame.font.SysFont("krabbypatty", 75)
HUGE_FONT = pygame.font.SysFont("krabbypatty", 150)
IMG = pygame.image.load("snakehead.png")
APPLE_IMG = pygame.image.load("apple10pix.png")
DIRECTION = "up"


def pause():
    paused = True
    message_to_screen("Paused",
                      BLACK,
                      Y_DISPLACE = -100,
                      size = "huge")
    message_to_screen("Press C to continue or Q to quit.",
                      BLACK,
                      Y_DISPLACE = 25)
    pygame.display.update()
    while paused:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key in (pygame.K_c, pygame.K_p):
                    paused = False
                elif event.key in(pygame.K_q, pygame.K_ESCAPE):
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()
        CLOCK.tick(5)

def score(score):
    text = SMALL_FONT.render("Score: " + str(score), True, BLACK)
    gameDisplay.blit(text, [0, 0])
    pygame.display.update

def game_intro():
    intro = True
    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_c:
                    intro = False
                if event.key in (pygame.K_q, pygame.K_ESCAPE):
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()
        gameDisplay.fill(WHITE)
        message_to_screen("Welcome to",
                          GREEN,
                          Y_DISPLACE = -170,
                          size = "large")
        message_to_screen("Block Worm",
                          GREEN,
                          Y_DISPLACE = -50,
                          size = "huge")
        message_to_screen("The objective of the game is to eat apples.",
                          BLACK,
                          Y_DISPLACE = 36,
                          size = "tiny")
        message_to_screen("The more apples you eat the longer you get.",
                          BLACK,
                          Y_DISPLACE = 68,
                          size = "tiny")
        message_to_screen("If you run into yourself or the edges, you die.",
                          BLACK,
                          Y_DISPLACE = 100,
                          size = "tiny")
        message_to_screen("Press C to play or Q to quit.",
                          GREY,
                          Y_DISPLACE = 210,)
        pygame.display.update()
        CLOCK.tick(FPS)

def snake(SNAKE_SIZE, SNAKE_LIST):
    if DIRECTION == "right":
        HEAD = pygame.transform.rotate(IMG, 270)
    elif DIRECTION == "left":
        HEAD = pygame.transform.rotate(IMG, 90)
    elif DIRECTION == "down":
        HEAD = pygame.transform.rotate(IMG, 180)
    else:
        DIRECTION == "up"
        HEAD = IMG
    gameDisplay.blit(HEAD, (SNAKE_LIST[-1][0], SNAKE_LIST[-1][1]))
    for XnY in SNAKE_LIST[:-1]:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, GREEN, [XnY[0], XnY[1], SNAKE_SIZE, SNAKE_SIZE])
        pygame.display.update

def text_objects(text, color, size):
    if size == "tiny":
        TEXT_SURFACE = TINY_FONT.render(text, True, color)
    elif size == "small":
        TEXT_SURFACE = SMALL_FONT.render(text, True, color)
    elif size == "medium":
        TEXT_SURFACE = MED_FONT.render(text, True, color)
    elif size == "large":
        TEXT_SURFACE = LARGE_FONT.render(text, True, color)
    elif size == "huge":
        TEXT_SURFACE = HUGE_FONT.render(text, True, color)
    return TEXT_SURFACE, TEXT_SURFACE.get_rect()

def message_to_screen(msg, color, Y_DISPLACE = 0, size = "small"):
    TEXT_SURF, TEXT_RECT = text_objects(msg, color, size)
    TEXT_RECT.center = (SCREEN[0] / 2), (SCREEN[1] / 2) + Y_DISPLACE
    gameDisplay.blit(TEXT_SURF, TEXT_RECT)

def randAppleGen():
    randAppleX = random.randrange(0, (SCREEN[0] - APPLE_SIZE), APPLE_SIZE)
    randAppleY = random.randrange(0, (SCREEN[1]- APPLE_SIZE), APPLE_SIZE)
    return randAppleX, randAppleY

def gameLoop():
    global DIRECTION
    gameExit = False
    gameOver = False

    SNAKE_LIST = [] # Where the snake head has been.
    SNAKE_LENGTH = 1 #Length that the snake starts.

    lead_x = (SCREEN[0] / 2)
    lead_y = (SCREEN[1] - (SCREEN[1] / 5))
    move_speed = 10
    move_speed_neg = move_speed * -1
    lead_x_change = 0
    lead_y_change = -move_speed

    randAppleX, randAppleY = randAppleGen()

    while not gameExit:
        if gameOver == True:
            message_to_screen("Game over",
                              RED,
                              Y_DISPLACE = -50,
                              size = "huge")
            message_to_screen("Press C to play again or Q to quit.",
                              BLACK,
                              Y_DISPLACE = 50,
                              size = "small")
            pygame.display.update()
        while gameOver == True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    gameExit = True
                    gameOver = False
                elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                        gameOver = False
                        gameExit = True
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_c:
                        gameLoop()

        # Handles arrow key and WASD events.
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameExit = True
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key in (pygame.K_LEFT, pygame.K_a):
                    lead_x_change = move_speed_neg
                    lead_y_change = 0
                    DIRECTION = "left"
                elif event.key in (pygame.K_RIGHT, pygame.K_d):
                    lead_x_change = move_speed
                    lead_y_change = 0
                    DIRECTION = "right"
                elif event.key in (pygame.K_UP, pygame.K_w):
                    lead_y_change = move_speed_neg
                    lead_x_change = 0
                    DIRECTION = "up"
                elif event.key in (pygame.K_DOWN, pygame.K_s):
                    lead_y_change = move_speed
                    lead_x_change = 0
                    DIRECTION = "down"
                elif event.key in (pygame.K_p, pygame.K_ESCAPE):
                    pause()

        # If the snake goes beyond the screen borders the game will end.
        if lead_x >= SCREEN[0] or lead_x < 0 or lead_y >= SCREEN[1] or lead_y <0:
            gameOver = True

        lead_x += lead_x_change
        lead_y += lead_y_change

        gameDisplay.fill(WHITE)

        # Draw the apple on screen
        APPLE_RECT = pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, RED, [randAppleX, randAppleY, APPLE_SIZE, APPLE_SIZE])
        if APPLE_RECT in SNAKE_LIST:
            APPLE_RECT #If the apple appears anywhere "under" the snake, it will immediately respawn elsewhere.

        # Draw the snake on screen
        SNAKE_HEAD = []
        SNAKE_HEAD.append(lead_x)
        SNAKE_HEAD.append(lead_y)
        SNAKE_LIST.append(SNAKE_HEAD)
        # If you hit yourself, game over.
        if SNAKE_HEAD in SNAKE_LIST[:-1]:
           gameOver = True
        if len(SNAKE_LIST) > SNAKE_LENGTH:
            del SNAKE_LIST[0]
        snake(SNAKE_SIZE, SNAKE_LIST)

        score(SNAKE_LENGTH - 1)

        # If the snake eats the apple
        if APPLE_RECT.collidepoint(lead_x, lead_y) == True:
            randAppleX, randAppleY = randAppleGen()
            SNAKE_LENGTH += 1

        pygame.display.update()
        CLOCK.tick(FPS)
    pygame.quit()
    quit()

game_intro()
gameLoop()
```

It's a pretty solid little game. But I want to make the snake and apple into classes so that I can later spawn other types of snakes (perhaps basic AI?) and other types of apples (maybe ones that are green that grow your snake 3+). I made an attempt at doing this myself with a snake class:

```
import pygame
import time
import random

pygame.init()

WHITE = (pygame.Color("white"))
BLACK = (  0,   0,  0)
RED   = (245,   0,  0)
TURQ  = (pygame.Color("turquoise"))
GREEN = (  0, 155,  0)
GREY  = ( 90,  90, 90)
SCREEN = (800, 600)
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode(SCREEN)
#Set the window title and picture
pygame.display.set_caption('Block Worm')
ICON = pygame.image.load("apple10pix.png")

pygame.display.set_icon(ICON)
CLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 20
FONT = pygame.font.SysFont("arial", 25)
APPLE_SIZE = 10
TINY_FONT = pygame.font.SysFont("candara", 15)
SMALL_FONT = pygame.font.SysFont("candara", 25)
MED_FONT = pygame.font.SysFont("candara", 50)
LARGE_FONT = pygame.font.SysFont("krabbypatty", 75)
HUGE_FONT = pygame.font.SysFont("krabbypatty", 150)
IMG = pygame.image.load("snakehead.png")
APPLE_IMG = pygame.image.load("apple10pix.png")


def pause():
    paused = True
    message_to_screen("Paused",
                      BLACK,
                      Y_DISPLACE = -100,
                      size = "huge")
    message_to_screen("Press C to continue or Q to quit.",
                      BLACK,
                      Y_DISPLACE = 25)
    pygame.display.update()
    while paused:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key in (pygame.K_c, pygame.K_p):
                    paused = False
                elif event.key in(pygame.K_q, pygame.K_ESCAPE):
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()
        CLOCK.tick(5)

def score(score):
    text = SMALL_FONT.render("Score: " + str(score), True, BLACK)
    gameDisplay.blit(text, [5, 5])
    pygame.display.update

def game_intro():
    intro = True
    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_c:
                    intro = False
                if event.key in (pygame.K_q, pygame.K_ESCAPE):
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()
        gameDisplay.fill(WHITE)
        message_to_screen("Welcome to",
                          GREEN,
                          Y_DISPLACE = -170,
                          size = "large")
        message_to_screen("Block Worm",
                          GREEN,
                          Y_DISPLACE = -50,
                          size = "huge")
        message_to_screen("The objective of the game is to eat apples.",
                          BLACK,
                          Y_DISPLACE = 36,
                          size = "tiny")
        message_to_screen("The more apples you eat the longer you get.",
                          BLACK,
                          Y_DISPLACE = 68,
                          size = "tiny")
        message_to_screen("If you run into yourself or the edges, you die.",
                          BLACK,
                          Y_DISPLACE = 100,
                          size = "tiny")
        message_to_screen("Press C to play or Q to quit.",
                          GREY,
                          Y_DISPLACE = 210,)
        pygame.display.update()
        CLOCK.tick(FPS)

def text_objects(text, color, size):
    if size == "tiny":
        TEXT_SURFACE = TINY_FONT.render(text, True, color)
    elif size == "small":
        TEXT_SURFACE = SMALL_FONT.render(text, True, color)
    elif size == "medium":
        TEXT_SURFACE = MED_FONT.render(text, True, color)
    elif size == "large":
        TEXT_SURFACE = LARGE_FONT.render(text, True, color)
    elif size == "huge":
        TEXT_SURFACE = HUGE_FONT.render(text, True, color)
    return TEXT_SURFACE, TEXT_SURFACE.get_rect()

def message_to_screen(msg, color, Y_DISPLACE = 0, size = "small"):
    TEXT_SURF, TEXT_RECT = text_objects(msg, color, size)
    TEXT_RECT.center = (SCREEN[0] / 2), (SCREEN[1] / 2) + Y_DISPLACE
    gameDisplay.blit(TEXT_SURF, TEXT_RECT)

def randAppleGen():
    randAppleX = random.randrange(0, (SCREEN[0] - APPLE_SIZE), APPLE_SIZE)
    randAppleY = random.randrange(0, (SCREEN[1]- APPLE_SIZE), APPLE_SIZE)
    return randAppleX, randAppleY

class Snake:
    def __init__(self, image, x, y, direction, speed):
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.width = self.rect.width
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.direction = direction
        self.speed = speed
        self.trail = [] # Where the snake head has been.
        self.length = 1 # Length that the snake starts.
    def snake_direction_change(direction):
        if direction == "right":
            self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, 270)
        elif direction == "left":
            self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, 90)
        elif direction == "down":
            self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, 180)
        else:
            direction == "up"
        pygame.display.update
    def snake_grow(x, y, z):
        gameDisplay.blit(self.image, (self.trail[-1][0], self.trail[-1][1]))
        for XnY in snake.trail[:-1]:
            pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, GREEN, [XnY[0], XnY[1], self.width, self.width])
            pygame.display.update


def gameLoop():
    gameExit = False
    gameOver = False

    lead_x_change = 0
    lead_y_change = -snake.speed

    randAppleX, randAppleY = randAppleGen()

    gameDisplay.fill(WHITE)

    snake = Snake(IMG,
                  x = (SCREEN[0] / 2),
                  y =(SCREEN[1] - (SCREEN[1] / 5)),
                  direction = "up",
                  speed = 10,)

    while not gameExit:
        if gameOver == True:
            message_to_screen("Game over",
                              RED,
                              Y_DISPLACE = -50,
                              size = "huge")
            message_to_screen("Press C to play again or Q to quit.",
                              BLACK,
                              Y_DISPLACE = 50,
                              size = "small")
            pygame.display.update()
        while gameOver == True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    gameExit = True
                    gameOver = False
                elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                        gameOver = False
                        gameExit = True
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_c:
                        gameLoop()

        # Handles arrow key and WASD events.
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameExit = True
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key in (pygame.K_LEFT, pygame.K_a):
                    lead_x_change = snake.speed * -1
                    lead_y_change = 0
                    snake.snake_direction_change("left")
                elif event.key in (pygame.K_RIGHT, pygame.K_d):
                    lead_x_change = snake.speed
                    lead_y_change = 0
                    snake.snake_direction_change("right")
                elif event.key in (pygame.K_UP, pygame.K_w):
                    lead_y_change = snake.speed * -1
                    lead_x_change = 0
                    snake.snake_direction_change("up")
                elif event.key in (pygame.K_DOWN, pygame.K_s):
                    lead_y_change = snake.speed
                    lead_x_change = 0
                    snake.snake_direction_change("down")
                elif event.key in (pygame.K_p, pygame.K_ESCAPE):
                    pause()

        # If the snake goes beyond the screen borders the game will end.
        if snake.rect.x >= SCREEN[0] or snake.rect.x < 0 or snake.rect.y >= SCREEN[1] or snake.rect.y <0:
            gameOver = True

        snake.rect.x += lead_x_change
        snake.rect.y += lead_y_change

        gameDisplay.fill(WHITE)

        # Draw the apple on screen
        APPLE_RECT = pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, RED, [randAppleX, randAppleY, APPLE_SIZE, APPLE_SIZE])
        if APPLE_RECT in snake.trail:
            APPLE_RECT #If the apple appears anywhere "under" the snake, it will immediately respawn elsewhere.

        # Draw the snake on screen
        SNAKE_HEAD = []
        SNAKE_HEAD.append(snake.rect.x)
        SNAKE_HEAD.append(snake.rect.y)
        snake.trail.append(SNAKE_HEAD)
        # If you hit yourself, game over.
        if SNAKE_HEAD in snake.trail[:-1]:
            gameOver = True
        if len(snake.trail) > snake.length:
            del snake.trail[0]
        snake.snake_grow(snake.width, snake.trail)

        score(snake.length - 1)

        # If the snake eats the apple
        if APPLE_RECT.collidepoint(snake.rect.x, snake.rect.y) == True:
            randAppleX, randAppleY = randAppleGen()
            snake.length += 1

        pygame.display.update()
        CLOCK.tick(FPS)
    pygame.quit()
    quit()

game_intro()
gameLoop()
```

This version isn't nearly as cute. In fact, it doesn't work at all. My understanding off classes and functions is elementary at best. A lot of code from the original was changed or completely deleted in my trial and error processes. I spent several hours trying to make this work to no avail. My main goal was to produce a Snake and Apple class that can be reused for later variations of both of them.

So, I've come to you fine folks to assist me! I have two main questions:

1) What do I have to do to make this work properly?

2) How can I clean up my code to make it easier to read and more efficient overall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**"A lot of code from the original was changed or completely deleted in my trial and error processes"**

**Bingo.**  You just found the crux of your issue.  Software development should be a controlled, thought out process - not trial and error.  You need to proceed thoughtfully, and  purposefully.

What you are trying to do (or should be trying to do) when introducing classes is [refactoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring) your code.

You should start again with the original, working copy, and proceed to change as little as possible when you introduce a Snake class.  The first step would be to simply convert your `snake` function into a class, and substitute that in.  Below is where you might start: replace your `snake` method with this `Snake` class, and change the line where you use it

```
class Snake:
    def __init__(self, SNAKE_SIZE, SNAKE_LIST):
        if DIRECTION == "right":
            HEAD = pygame.transform.rotate(IMG, 270)
        elif DIRECTION == "left":
            HEAD = pygame.transform.rotate(IMG, 90)
        elif DIRECTION == "down":
            HEAD = pygame.transform.rotate(IMG, 180)
        else:
            DIRECTION == "up"  # note: this line does nothing
            HEAD = IMG
        gameDisplay.blit(HEAD, (SNAKE_LIST[-1][0], SNAKE_LIST[-1][1]))
        for XnY in SNAKE_LIST[:-1]:
            pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, GREEN, [XnY[0], XnY[1], SNAKE_SIZE, SNAKE_SIZE])
            pygame.display.update  # note: this likely does nothing - I think you want to call it (pygame.display.update())
```

and change this:

```
snake(SNAKE_SIZE, SNAKE_LIST)
```

into:

```
snake = Snake(SNAKE_SIZE, SNAKE_LIST)
```

Now at this point, if your code worked before, it should still work (assuming I haven't done anything silly).  Is this a good example of a class?  No.  **My Snake class is terrible.  Your attempt at a snake class is far, far better.**  Doing things this way gives you a starting point though.  You can then proceed to do things like:

- assign the parameters to instance variables
- move pretty much all the code into another method
- start removing the module-level variables it has access to, and pass in additional arguments
- etc.

An alternate way to refactor this module might be to change each of your functions so that none of them rely on module level variables. Pass every variable that each function needs into that function.

The main point I'd like to leave you with is that it is far easier to make working software by writing/changing just a little at a time.  Make sure it still works before changing something else.  Work on small bits of code & test each change so you'll know exactly where and how your program broke.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Your post seems like such common sense that I'm a little embarrassed I wasn't approaching it that way to start with. I've made a lot of progress.

Comment: @austi:  Don't beat yourself up.  We're all learning.  If this is an acceptable answer to your question, you should [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/154630)